# Cannot add connection to MySQL in C# application

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect MySQL to Windows following the instructions given [here](http://www.dscripts.net/tutorials/2009/01/18/connect-to-mysql-database-using-csharp/).

I have installed MySQL 5.1 software, GUI tools and MySQL connector. MySQL is working fine.

I want to establish connection between the MySQL database and a C# Windows application.
But I am not able to find "MySql.Data" in **add references tab** in the C# Windows application. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Please refer to the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show anything past Mi* - are you sure you scrolled down to My* in the list to look for your assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have the [Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html) installed, it ought to show up in the .NET tab.

If not you can just click the Browse tab, and add the assembly directly, it should be under

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector
>   Net 6.0.4\Assemblies

or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

How about browsing to the DLL (browse tab)?